# Cauchy's Integral Theorem - Verification of Proof Based on Heine-Borel

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

**Question**: Is the following proof relating to the Cauchy's Integral Theorem valid?

**Assumptions**: I assume the following key theorems

*Theorem 1. A nonempty open set in the plane is connected if and only if any two of its points can be joined by a polygon which lies in the set.*  This is from Ahlfors, Complex Analysis (Third Edition), pp. 56-57.

*Theorem 2.  A holomorphic function in an open disk has a primitive in that disk.*   This is from
Stein & Shakarchi, Complex Analysis, pp. 37-39.

*Theorem 3. The set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact if and only if every open covering
of $K$ has a finite subcovering.*  This is from various sources.

**Theorem and Proof:**

*Theorem*. Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a simply connected set and let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $\Omega$.  Then $f$ has a primitive in $\Omega$.

*Proof*.
Fix points $z_0,\, z \in\Omega$. From Theorem 1, there is a polygon
$P_z \subset \Omega$ that joins $z_0$ (the beginning point) and $z$ (the ending point). We use $P_z$ as our contour of integration and define
\begin{equation*}
F(z) = \int_{P_z} f(w)\kern{1pt} dw.
\end{equation*}
We will show that $F$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ with $F'(z) = f(z)$.

*Create Finite Subcover of $P_z$*.
Our polygon $P_z$ consists of a finite number of connected straight line segments
$L_1, L_2, ... L_m$.  For each such line segment, we proceed as follows.  For each point $s\in L_j$, let $D_j(s)$ be an open disk that is centered at $s$ and small enough so that $D_j(s)\subset \Omega$.  Define
\begin{equation*}
A_j = \bigcup_{s\in L_j} D_j(s).
\end{equation*}
Then $A_j$ is an open cover of $L_j$.  Because $L_j$ is compact, by Theorem 3 (Heine-Borel) the open cover $A_j$ has a finite subcover
$S_j$.  If we combine our finite subcovers as follows
\begin{equation*}
S = \bigcup_{j=1}^m S_j,
\end{equation*}
then $S$ is a finite subcover of $P_z$.  Note that $S$ consists of open disks centered at points
$s_1, s_2, ...s_k$, with all $s_j\in P_z$.  The disk associated with point $s_j$ will be called $D_j$.

*Modify Finite Subcover of $P_z$*.
First, reorder our points $s_1, s_2, ...s_k$ so they are numbered in the order they appear in a transversal of $P_z$ from $z_0$ to $z$.
Next, repeat the following instructions as many times as necessary: (1) For all $j$, if $D_j\subset D_{j+1}$ or $D_j\subset D_{j-1}$, we remove $D_j$ (and its associated point $s_j$) from our subcover, and (2) as needed, we renumber our points $s_j$ to account for the removed items.

We have removed from our subcover any disk that is fully enclosed in the interior of the disk of an immediate neighbor.  Importantly, in the construction of our subcover, we have ensured that all points on $P_z$ between $z_0$ and $s_k$ are fully covered by disks $D_1$ through $D_k$. (We are not relying on any "rogue" disks further down the polygon).  That means disks $D_j$ and $D_{j+1}$ always *partially* intersect.

After our modifications, we will assume that there are $k$ (ordered) open disks $D_j$ remaining.

*Divide $P_z$ into Sub-Contours*.
For $j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq j < k$, let $I_j = P_z \cap D_j \cap D_{j+1}$ and choose a point $p_j \in I_j$.  We have selected points $p_1, p_2, ...p_{k-1}$, all on $P_z$ and in order of
of a transversal of $P_z$ from $z_0$ to $z$.  We also define $p_0 = z_0$ and $p_k = z$.
For $j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq j \leq k$, now define the contour $C_j$ as the (closed) section of $P_z$ that begins at $p_{j-1}$ and ends at $p_j$.  We have
\begin{equation*}
P_z = \bigcup_{j=1}^k C_j.
\end{equation*}

*The Finish*.
Observe that $C_j \subset D_j$.  By Theorem 2, our function $f\,$ has a primitive in each $D_j$.  That allows
\begin{equation*}
F(z) = \int_{P_z} f(w)\kern{1pt} dw = \sum_{j=1}^k \int_{C_j} f(w)\kern{1pt} dw,
\end{equation*}
showing that $F$ is a primitive of $f$ in $\Omega$, as required.